# Bit packing in yuv420p10le(tv) format

Tags: video, yuv, hdr

For YUV420 10 bit semiplanar format (also called as P010 as described in [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/10-bit-and-16-bit-yuv-video-formats#420-formats)) the data arrangement is as follows,

1. Y (luma) is stored in a plane with each pixel taking a word  (16 bit)
2. U and V (chroma) is stored in a seperate plane together in interleaved format. UV takes 32 bit together. Least significant word is U, MSW is V

Question is within 16bit, how are the 10bit data packed. Does pixel data start from 0th bit to 10th bit,  or from 6th bit to 16th bit? The explanation is not clear in MSDN. Pointing out the corresponding spec in standard will also be helpful

Comment: did you solve this or do you still need help?

Comment: yes, I resolved it. 
LSB is empty, MSB 10bits are valid data.

Answer (score 0):

There is p010le and p010be. Little and big endian. So, it depends, you may wanna look how it works in ffmpeg and VAAPI.

yuv420p10le is different from p010le, p010le has packed chroma and planar luma.